# Change size of newform.aspx when clicking new item

Tags: custom-form, form, newform

I want to know if there's a way to change the size of newform.aspx, by default it looks narrow, but my design states that I need more space to display my form without having to scroll right or left, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. At least in SharePoint 2013 on-prem

First create a new custom form. Go to the list where you want the new form and edit the form in SharePoint Designer.

[image]

Then create a new form (1), give it a name (2), select which kind of form (3), option to set it als default (4) and click ok (5).

[image]

Then open the newly created form in advanced mode (right click on the new form):

[image]

In my environment it is line 24 where you can edit / change the width of the form.

[image]

Hope it helped. Also posted the guide in my [blog](https://afrait.com/blog/custom-new-edit-or-display-form-in-4-steps-en/).

Comment: That's amazing, but the measurement here is in points or pixels? I tried making it: 800px, but that ruined the whole form, so I just made it 800, but is it 800 px , pt, em?

Comment: I tested it with "400px" and at least it worked. As I know it should be in px, but not 100% sure. Also updated the answer a little bit to give everybody a kind of step-by-step guide.

Comment: I read this post as I'm researching using signature pads and needed to try and increase the size of my signature field.  Anyway, I thought I'd mention that you could also use the zoom in and out on the browser - maybe that might help someone too (depending on what you want to achieve).  Incidentally, this did not help with the signature field I'm working on.