# How to edit the New and Edit forms on a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I want to do the following:
On the 'New' form I want to hide various settings of the list
On the edit form I want to see these settings.

I know I can use info path to design these forms but how do I select JUST the New form or just the Edit form.
Is there any other way of designing a form than using Info path?

Comment: Here you might get the first steps to do so: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158188/change-size-of-newform-aspx-when-clicking-new-item/158192#158192

Answer (score 3):

Open Your site on SharePoint Designer ---> Click on List & Libraries Tab in Navigation Quick Launch ---> You will get your ListName and then click on your List ---> Now in the Right side below View section in the Forms section click on the new button on the right side the dialog box will open where you can design your New & Edit Forms.

You can refer below links,

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/09/20/how-to-create-custom-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have development skills, you can also use JSLink. JSLink allows you to attach custom CSR code to a form (View, Display, New or Edit). You could use the same file for the different form, and add a logic to check what kind of form your in, or use different files.

Here is a basic example : http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/customize-list-form-fields-in-display-form-dispform-aspx-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013-2/