# Is is possible to create an Infopath 2010 form to use with an SP 2013 asset library?

Tags: infopath, asset-library

I have created an asset library for our field users to upload videos. However, I have been asked to create a form for the process instead of using the OOB dialog box. I have discovered that the asset library does not allow me to create an Infopath form (unless I'm missing something). I need an OOB solution that would allow me to provide a clean simple form for the end user. No 3rd party products. Any suggestions? I'm using Infopath 2010 and SharePoint 2013 (on-premise).

Comment: Take a look here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164092/how-to-edit-the-new-and-edit-forms-on-a-sharepoint-list